# What is the wrong with updating the user information in this ListView?

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an intranet web-based application which has a part for managing its users. I am trying to develop this part using a ListView Control. Everything works fine except updating the information of the employee. Before explaining the problem, let me explain to you the database design:
Employee Table: Username, Name, DivisionCode
Division Table: DivisionCode, Division
(The first attribute in each table is the primary key)

I have a problem with updating the division for the employee and when I tried to do, I got the following error:
Invalid column name 'Username'.

My ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Username" 
                 DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

                 <EditItemTemplate>
                     <tr style="">
                         <td>
                             <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                                 Text="Update" />
                             <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                                 Text="Cancel" />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:TextBox ID="JobTitleTextBox" runat="server" 
                                 Text='<%# Bind("JobTitle") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:TextBox ID="BadgeNoTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BadgeNo") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:TextBox ID="DivisionShortcutTextBox" runat="server" 
                                 Text='<%# Bind("DivisionShortcut") %>' />
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </EditItemTemplate>
                 <EmptyDataTemplate>
                     <table runat="server" style="">
                         <tr>
                             <td>
                                 No data was returned.</td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </EmptyDataTemplate>
                 <InsertItemTemplate>
                     <tr style="">
                         <td>
                             <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                                 Text="Insert" />
                             <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                                 Text="Clear" />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" runat="server" 
                                 Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:TextBox ID="JobTitleTextBox" runat="server" 
                                 Text='<%# Bind("JobTitle") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:TextBox ID="BadgeNoTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BadgeNo") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:TextBox ID="DivisionShortcutTextBox" runat="server" 
                                 Text='<%# Bind("DivisionShortcut") %>' />
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </InsertItemTemplate>
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="images/delete.png" Width="20px" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />
                             <%--<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                            Text="Delete" />--%>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="images/edit.png" Width="20px" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                            <%--<asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />--%>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="SelectButton" ImageUrl="images/select.png" Width="20px" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                            <%--<asp:Button ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />--%>
                        </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="JobTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobTitle") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="BadgeNoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BadgeNo") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="DivisionShortcutLabel" runat="server" 
                                 Text='<%# Eval("DivisionShortcut") %>' />
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <LayoutTemplate>
                                 <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                     <tr runat="server" style="">
                                         <th runat="server">
                                             Name</th>
                                         <th runat="server">
                                             Username</th>
                                         <th runat="server">
                                             JobTitle</th>
                                         <th runat="server">
                                             BadgeNo</th>
                                         <th runat="server">
                                             Division</th>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                     </tr>
                                 </table>
                         <tr runat="server">
                             <td runat="server" style="">
                                 <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                                     <Fields>
                                         <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" 
                                             ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                                     </Fields>
                                 </asp:DataPager>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </LayoutTemplate>
                 <SelectedItemTemplate>
                     <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="images/delete.png" Width="20px" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />
                            <%--<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                                Text="Delete" />--%>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="images/edit.png" Width="20px" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                            <%--<asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />--%>
                        </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="JobTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobTitle") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="BadgeNoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BadgeNo") %>' />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="DivisionShortcutLabel" runat="server" 
                                 Text='<%# Eval("DivisionShortcut") %>' />
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </SelectedItemTemplate>
             </asp:ListView>
             <br />
             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                 SelectCommand="SELECT     dbo.employee.Name, dbo.employee.Username, dbo.employee.JobTitle, dbo.employee.BadgeNo, dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut
FROM         dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode"

                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Employee] WHERE [Username] = @Username"  

                UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Divisions] SET [DivisionShortcut] = @DivisionShortcut WHERE [Username] = @Username">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="DivisionShortcut" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>
             </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**How to fix this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

You might not have declared Username parameter in UpdateParameters

Comment: in updateParameters i can see only divisionshortcut no username